# How to check if internet through a certain interfaceaddress is up?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, network-interface

My pc is connected to 2 different interfaces that make access to the internet possible (a wired connection and a wifi connection to my smartphone that has mobile access, to be used in case the wired connection is lost).

When the wired connection has internet connection, I manually disconnect the other (mobile) connection at the DOS prompt :

```
netsh wlan disconnect interface="Wi-Fi"
```

Now i will check every minute or so if i can reach whatever site through the wired internet connection.

As soon as this fails, java will connect to the Wi-Fi connection again so that the loss of internet connection is minimal :

But here comes my problem : as soon as the wired internet is up and running again,  I want java to automatically connect through that interface address again and disconnect the "Wi-Fi" (to limit costs ...).

I don't know if it is possible to connect to a URL starting with a predefined IP address in order to find out when the wired connection is online again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution myself, as illustrated in following code (this code runs as a test, start it on a desktop with both a wired and a wifi connection, which automatically results in closing the mobile connection, then manually disconnect the wired connection which automatically opens the mobile connection again. As soon as you manually reconnect the wired connection, the mobile connection will be disconnected again).

```
package testingPackage;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class TestInternet {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int internet = 1;
int counter = 0;
while(counter<10){
    counter = counter + 1;
    int connections = 0;
    Socket[] soc = new Socket[10];
    try{
        NetworkInterface nif = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth1");
        //the right name of the wired internet can be found with following code in between  /* … */
        /*
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface interf = interfaces.nextElement();
            if (interf.isUp() && !interf.isLoopback()) {
                List<InterfaceAddress> adrs = interf.getInterfaceAddresses();
                for (Iterator<InterfaceAddress> iter = adrs.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                    InterfaceAddress adr = iter.next();
                    InetAddress inadr = adr.getAddress();
                    if (inadr instanceof Inet4Address){
                        NetworkInterface nif1 = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(inadr);
                        System.out.println("L30 = "+nif1);
                    } 
                }
            }
        } 
        */
        Enumeration<InetAddress> nifAddresses = nif.getInetAddresses();
        while (nifAddresses.hasMoreElements()){
            soc[connections] = new java.net.Socket();
            soc[connections].bind(new InetSocketAddress(nifAddresses.nextElement(), 0));
            connections = connections + 1;
        }
        soc[0].connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 80));
        if(internet==0){
            System.out.println("Internet is BACK, throw out the mobile internet now !");
            try{
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"netsh", "wlan", "disconnect", "interface=Wi-Fi"});
                internet = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception e2) {System.out.println("Warning : Could not disconnect the mobile network !");  }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Internet is UP");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("enumeration failed");connections  = 0;
        System.out.println("Internet is still DOWN, connect to mobile internet now !");
        connections  = 0;
        internet = 0;
        //find SSID name, profile name and interface name of the wired and wireless network in DOS :
            //netsh wlan show networks : returns the SSID name XXXX
            //netsh wlan show profile (REQUIRED): returns the profile name YYYY
            //netsh wlan show interfaces : returns the interface name
        try{
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"netsh", "wlan", "connect","ssid=XXXX", "name=YYYY", "interface=Wi-Fi"});
        }
        catch (Exception e2) {System.out.println("Warning : no internet ! Could not connect to mobile network !");  }
    }
    System.out.println("number of wired connections = "+connections);
    try {Thread.sleep(10000);} 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println("no sleep"); }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Although this solution works for me, it's not exactly what I was looking for : this code only works with a mobile WIFI connection. What I really want is a  mobile USB connection to the PC, which seems more reliable to me. But untill now I couldn't find how java can disconnect that kind of connection automatically. If someone knows the answer, please post it here as a note !